# How to update model attribute via command on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to generate custom app with template
and enable devise confirmable option,by the link
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users.

I can add column , index , unique , by

```
 #add confirmable
 confirm_cols='confirmation_token:string:index:unique confirmed_at:datetime confirmation_sent_at:datetime'
 run "rails g migration add_confirmable_to_user #{confirm_cols}"
```

in my template file,but I don't know how to run

```
User.update_all(:confirmed_at => Time.now
```

in command line. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gotta be honest, it's not totally clear what you're asking, but I think you're saying you just want to run that one command to update all the user's. You can do that by either opening the rails console or using rails running:

```
rails runner "User.update_all(:confirmed_at => Time.now)"
```